# Word metric on $ℤ$ with generating set {$p,q$} where $p,q>1$ are coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric) of word metric gives an example: the group $(ℤ,+)$ is generated by $1$, so the distance between $0$ and $n$ in the word metric is $|n|$.

Can you compute the word metric on $ℤ$, with generating set {$p,q$} where $p,q>1$ are coprime?
This is equivalent to find minimum of $|x|+|y|$ such that $px+qy=n$ over integers $x,y$.

For example $\{2,3\}$, I compute:
If $n=3k,k∈ℤ$, then the distance between $0$ and $n$ is $|k|$.
If $n=3k+1,k>0$, then $n=3(k-1)+2\times2$, the distance between $0,n$ is $k-1+2=k+1$.
If $n=3k+1,k\le0$, then $n=3(k+1)-2$, the distance between $0,n$ is $|k+1|+1=-k$.
If $n=3k+2,k∈ℤ$, then $n=3k+2$, the distance between $0,n$ is $|k|+1$.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @ joriki My question is to write down the distance between $0$ and $n$ in the word metric of Z with generators $p,q$

Comment: Might as well make $x_0 = nr$ and $y_0 = ns$, where $r$ and $s$ such that $pr+qs=1$ can be found via the Euclidean algorithm. This way you don't need this mysterious $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Ok, I answered the question

Answer (score 0):

All integer solutions of $px+qy=n$ are $(x,y)=(nr+qt,ns-pt),t∈ℤ$
($r$ and $s$ such that $pr+qs=1$ can be found via the Euclidean algorithm.)

Then the distance between $0,n$ is the minimum of $|nr+qt|+|ns-pt|$ over $t∈ℤ$.
When $|nr+qt|+|ns-pt|$ is minimal, one of $|nr+qt|,|ns-pt|$ is minimal, so $t=\lfloor-\frac{nr}q\rfloor$ or $t=\lceil-\frac{nr}q\rceil$ or $t=\lfloor\frac{ns}p\rfloor$ or $t=\lceil\frac{ns}p\rceil$